# hive column relationship

Tags: sql, hive

i have a a list of data ex:

```
number                  fruit
1                       apple
1                       banana
1                       orange
2                       orange
3                       orange
3                       grape
4                       apple
```

How can i query in hive columns where a number can have multiple fruits under it so the revised query will bring up

```
1                       apple
1                       banana
1                       orange
3                       orange
3                       grape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best way is to use window functions.  If rows cannot  have duplicate number/fruit pairs:

```
select number, fruit
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by number) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

If you can have duplicates and you want 2 or more *different* fruits, you can do:

```
select number, fruit
from (select t.*,
             min(fruit) over (partition by number) as min_fruit,
             max(fruit) over (partition by number) as max_fruit
      from t
     ) t
where min_fruit <> max_fruit;
```

And finally, for this situation, you can phrase this in SQL for most databases efficiently as:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.number = t.number and t2.fruit <> t.fruit);
```

However, I don't think the correlated subquery would be efficient in Hive (if it is even allowed in your version).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where number in (select number from your_table group by number having count(*) > 1)
```